# Export Relationship data using Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel to export data. I want to get all the reminders attached to a vet, which are accessed over a hasManyThrough relationship.

I have tried the following code

**RemindersExport.php**

```
public function collection()
{
    $vets = Vet::where('is_active', 1)->get();

    foreach($vets as $vet){
        $reminders = $vet->reminders();
    }

    return $reminders;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function reminders()
{
    return Excel::download(new RemindersExport, 'reminders30days.xlsx');
}
```

I get the following message...

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all does not exist.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, as I can see, where you used `someModel::all()` ?

Comment: are you trying to return Vets and Reminders together?  If so I recommend this: Vet::where('is_active', 1)with->('reminders')->get();

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the collection method but you should use the query method and laravel-excel excecutes the query for you so you don't have to use the get method at the end of your query, first you sould use the FromQuery concern, after that you should replace your collection method with the query method, write your query and DON'T add the get method at the end of your query

```php
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;

class VetExport implements FromQuery{
    public function query()
    {
        $vets = Vet::where('is_active', 1);

        foreach($vets as $vet){
            $reminders = $vet->reminders();
        }

        return $reminders;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps